# Stepping down 12V to 5V without amperage loss

Tags: power-supply, led, buck, 5v

I'm building a LED wall but I'm having trouble finding a suitable PSU. I need a 5V one but all I can find are 12V 30A which if converted to 5V would be perfect.

My question is, is there a way to buck down the 12V to 5V without any loss of amperage? If so, how?

Comment: eBay sells 5V 40A power supplies for about $25, so I don't understand "i need a 5v one but all i can find are 12v 30 amps". If you can find 5V, but with not enough current, can you split the 'LED Wall' into sections and use more than one PSU?

Comment: What is "no current loss" supposed to mean? Do you need 30A at the output? Or do you not want any power loss?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if the OP had searched more he'd have found what he was looking for without waking anyone up!

Comment: @Andyaka: do you have the new questions feed wired up to your alarm clock? LOL. I agree with closure anyhow. The question is not even clear how many amps at 5V are needed...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "amperage loss" you mean "power loss". Any step-down converter has a non-100% efficiency. Simply by adding components that require some power to work. So no, you can't do that. But a decent buck converter gives around 90% efficiency which is good enough for most.

Comment: Actually he might just need/want a 5V 30A psu for all we know.

Comment: As long as he doesn't want a 30A linear regulator...